# how to transform a json file to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file that I would like to transform it as pandas dataframe.
the json file is:

```
{'lastUpdated': {'epochUnixSeconds': 1686580918,
  'humanDate': '2023-06-12T14:41:58.000Z'},
 'fgi': {'now': {'value': 78, 'valueText': 'Extreme Greed'},
  'previousClose': {'value': 77, 'valueText': 'Extreme Greed'},
  'oneWeekAgo': {'value': 73, 'valueText': 'Greed'},
  'oneMonthAgo': {'value': 57, 'valueText': 'Greed'},
  'oneYearAgo': {'value': 40, 'valueText': 'Fear'}}}
```

How to convert this json file into a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: I would like to have the value / ValueText for each column and now / previousClose / oneWeekAgo / oneMonthAgo / oneYearAgo as index